# AES crypting/decrypting on ios 6 issue

Tags: iphone, encryption, ios6

i'm trying to crypt/decrypt files using some libraries i found on web ( they use `CommonCrypto` ) ( links bellow ), but all libs have the same issue in ios6 ( and not in ios 5 ) :
 i crypt an image for example with "xx" as passWord, when i decrypt it, i have always a true result and as output a not nil data, if the password is "xx" the image is in the good format ( i can open it ) if no i can't, this is just in ios6. and i heard that ios 6 have problems with WPA2-AES crypted password: [ios6 wifi issue](http://www.dailygadgets.net/apples-ios-6-wi-fi-issues-linger-on/13652/) .

Is that a known issue ?
Can you tell me a way to do this on ios6?

links for used libs:
https://github.com/dev5tec/FBEncryptor
https://github.com/AlanQuatermain/aqtoolkit/tree/master/CommonCrypto
http://code.google.com/p/iphonebits/source/browse/trunk/src/Encryption/?r=2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you don't provide authentication/integrity protection for the cipher text, the code may always decrypt, even if the key is incorrect. AES block encryption is 1:1, a plain text message has exactly one cipher text, and a cipher text is always linked to a single plain text message. This means that if you provide the wrong key, the decryption will be a random value with the same size as the block.

Use a HMAC, preferably with another key, sign the messages or use an authenticated mode of encryption.

Comment: thank you, i solve the problem, i search for HMAC and i find https://github.com/rnapier/RNCryptor, this lib was having the same  issue (with iOS 6) but 'Rob' switch from CTR to CBC because ios6 doesn't support it.

Comment: You are welcome. Using `RNCryptor` seems to be a good idea. Rob knows what he's doing.